# JQuery selector tag SUB selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I just got started with Jquery... Well at least I just started to get the hang of it.
Now I am trying to switch contents from location a to location b

Now I have a selector of which I would like to fetch the HTML contents and place it at another location.
But the trouble is that I do not yet have any class defined. And the HTML code is used approx 900 times I don't want to change all of that.

```
        <table style="width: 100%" class="layout-table two">
        <tr>
            <td class="First">
                The source content
            </td>
            <td>
                <!--- HERE IT SHOULD BE!!!  AKA TARGET -->
                <h2>Welcome at my testcase</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer 
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is what the table looks like

```
            $(document).ready( function () {
            var SpecialSubmenu = $(".First").html();
            $( ".layout-table .First" ).html('');
            $( ".layout-table tr td" ).prepend( '<div id="TabletSubmenu" style="background: #CCCCCC;">' + SpecialSubmenu + '</div>' );
            $( "#TabletSubmenu" ).html( SpecialSubmenu );
            $( ".layout-table .First" ).remove();
        });
```

And this is what my JQuery code looks like.
It works however....
It works for all set tables within my HTML page.

Now I do know where I have made the mistake.
That's here :

```
$( ".layout-table tr td" ).prepend( '<div id="TabletSubmenu" style="background: #CCCCCC;">' + SpecialSubmenu + '</div>' );
```

In CSS it would indeed be : 
.layout-table tr td {
 some style...
}

But JQUery thinks otherwise. And I do not know how to select specifically the first TR and TD tag.

(after the removal of the previous one.)

Hope you understand my question.

TIAD!!

*EDIT*

What I meant:

I have

```
<table class="MyTable">
<tr>
    <td class="First">Source</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <!-- TARGET -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Something I want to remain</td>
                <td>And not change</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But what happened in my example is that not only at  My Code got added. But also at "**Something I want to remain**" AND "**And not change**"

Comment: So you want to move some content to the `.next()` td and then `.remove()` the empty one..?

Comment: question is not very clear at all. What repeats 900 times? What is your specific problem? `thinks otherwise` is not clear

Comment: Can't you just use the selector `$( ".layout-table .First td" )`? Also, please could you make the question clearer? I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination `:first` and `first()` or `:eq()` and `eq()` to get specific tr and td of the table :

```
$( ".layout-table tr:first td" ).first().prepend( '<div id="TabletSubmenu" style="background: #CCCCCC;">' + SpecialSubmenu + '</div>' );
```

or you can also use `:eq()` followied by `.first()`:

```
$( ".layout-table tr:eq(0) td" ).first().prepend( '<div id="TabletSubmenu" style="background: #CCCCCC;">' + SpecialSubmenu + '</div>' );
```

or use `:first` followed by `.eq(0)`:

```
$( ".layout-table tr:first td" ).eq(0).prepend( '<div id="TabletSubmenu" style="background: #CCCCCC;">' + SpecialSubmenu + '</div>' );
```

or completely use `:eq()` and `.eq()`:

```
$( ".layout-table tr:eq(0)td" ).eq(0).prepend( '<div id="TabletSubmenu" style="background: #CCCCCC;">' + SpecialSubmenu + '</div>' );
```

Comment: The first option worked for me :

`$( ".layout-table tr:first td" ).first().prepend( '<div id="TabletSubmenu" style="background: #CCCCCC;">' + SpecialSubmenu + '</div>' );`